# Using ls to launch a Python script on each subdirectory

Tags: bash

I created this little Python script *Essai_Bash.py* to make some tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', action='store', dest='InputDir', help='Working Directory') # Empty folders for outputs.

parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 0.1')

results = parser.parse_args()
print 'Current input directory      =', results.InputDir

dir_path=str(os.path.abspath(results.InputDir)) # Retrieving an output folder name to use as species ID:
path,CodeSp = os.path.split(dir_path)

print "Currently working on species:      "+str(CodeSp)
```

Back to my shell, I type the following command, expecting my script to run on each directory that is present in my "Essai_Bash" folder:

```
listdir='ls ../Main_folder/' # I first used backtips instead of simple quotes but it did not work.
for dir in $listdir; do ./Essai_Bash.py -i ../Main_folder/$dir; done
```

I am surely missing something obvious but it does not work. It seems like $listdir is considered as a characters strings and not a list of directories. However, just typing `$listdir` in my shell actually gives me this list!

Comment: You should be using backticks

Comment: Hi Dmitri, this is quite odd; I did this at the beginning and it did not work... I definitely should have missed something :) thank you very much!

Comment: You should *not* be using `ls` like this at all. `for dir in ../Main_folder/*; do ./Essai_Bash.py -i "$dir"; done`.

Comment: Thanks chepner, I recognize I am still new in using bash :) always good to learn something new!

Comment: Your title said "Using -ls ...", which was seriously confusing. I changed it to "Using ls ...", which I presume is what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

Just use glob extension, parsing ls output is not safe.
Also `dir` variable already contains `../Main_folder/`

```
listdir=( ../Main_folder/*/ )
for dir in "${listdir[@]}"; do ./Essai_Bash.py -i "$dir"; done
```

Comment: Thanks Nahuel! Have a very nice day :)